# How to sum array value with specific key

Tags: php, arrays

```
"accounts" => array:6 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "acc_id" => 1
      "balance" => 1000.00
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "acc_id" => 2
      "balance" => -1500.00
    ]
    2 => array:4 [
      "acc_id" => 3
      "balance" => 5000.00
    ]
]
```

Hi, How could I sum up all the balance correct?

Code

```
foreach ($y['accounts'] as $k) 
{
    $sum_balance = $k['balance'];           
}
$sum_balance += $sum_balance;
```

With this code, The result will only sum the last balance itself. Example result is `10000.00`

Comment: you are overwriting $sum_balance with every iteration of the loop, then double it after the loop. just go through your code line by line and actively try to understand what it is _doing_.

Answer (score 3):

You need to increment sum in the foreach loop:

```
$sum_balance = 0;
foreach ($y['accounts'] as $k) 
{
    $sum_balance += $k['balance'];           
}
var_dump($sum_balance);
```

Answer (score 3):

combine `array_sum()` with `array_column()`

`array_column()`

> Return the values from a single column in the input array

`array_sum()`

> Calculate the sum of values in an array

```php
$y = [
    'accounts' => [
        0 => [
          "acc_id" => 1,
          "balance" => 1000.00
        ],
        1 => [
          "acc_id" => 2,
          "balance" => -1500.00
        ],
        2 => [
          "acc_id" => 3,
          "balance" => 5000.00
        ]
    ]
];

var_dump(
    array_sum(array_column($y['accounts'], 'balance'))
);
```

#### result:`float 4500`

Comment: You might want to add some explanation for the OP and future readers.

Comment: It would be better if you matched OPs data structure, in which case you would want `array_sum(array_column($y['accounts'], 'balance'));`

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is almost correct, just initialize the `$sum_balance` before the loop and sum it inside the loop.

```
$sum_balance=0;
foreach ($y['accounts'] as $k) 
{
    $sum_balance += $k['balance'];           
}
```

Hope it helps, if you need any help feel free to connect.